# Is a function with just one point in its domain strictly ascending and strictly descending?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This is the definition of an strictly increasing and strictly decreasing function.

"A function $f(x)$ increases on an interval I if $f(b)\geq f(a)\;\;\forall b>a$, where $a,b \in I$. If $f(b)>f(a) \;\;\forall \;\;b>a$, the function is said to be strictly increasing.

Conversely, A function $f(x)$ decreases on an interval I if $f(b)≤f(a)\;\;\forall b>a$, where $a,b \in I$. If $f(b)<f(a) \;\;\forall \;\;b>a$, the function is said to be strictly decreasing.

Then how would a function with just one point in its domain be described?

Comment: What is your definition of one-point function? A function that has only a single point as its domain?

Comment: @yoyostein, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's both (strictly) increasing and (strictly) decreasing since there is no second point that can contradict the definitions.